# Create custom Xcode project template

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am working on a custom template for single view app on Xcode, I can add folders to project but I need to make template create folders in assets automatically like the image

[image]

I also need to move ViewController.swift into a subfolder, not create a new one (or remove the original and create a new one).

Comment: Right click on your ViewController.swift and click "New Group from Selection". It will move the selected file into a new subfolder of your project.

Comment: @drfalcoew I know how to create folder inside Xcode I need to create folder form template automatically custom template